# Django Custom User did not log in

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I've created a CustomUser from AbstractUser in Django 1.9. Add on `admin.sites.register` when I was create superuser, django have created successful but when I was log in on system the user didn't exists.
Follow the code:

On `customuser/models.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, cpf, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            cpf=cpf
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, cpf, password):
        user = self.create_user(username, email, first_name, last_name, cpf,
                                password=password)
        user.is_super_user = True
        user.save()
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    SEXO_CHOICES = (
        (u'Masculino', u'Masculino'),
        (u'Feminino', u'Feminino'),
    )

    cpf = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    is_super_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data_de_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'cpf']
objects = CustomUserManager()
```

On `settins.py`, I add the line:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'customuser',
]

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customuser.CustomUser'
```

And my `customuser/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import CustomUser, CustomUserManager


admin.site.register(CustomUser)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Where do you use the `CustomUserManager` custom manager? Should not there be `objects = CustomUserManager()` defined on the model?

Comment: Sorry. I forget to copy. I correct it now. This code was there. This is not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you indented `objects = ...` properly?

Answer (score 0):

[See these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin) on making custom user work with admin site.

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, previously I thought, you were inheriting your model from `AbstractBaseUser`, therefore that answer was giving you error.

Since, you're inheriting from `AbstractUser`, your subclass will automatically get `is_staff` field. So, you'll just need to set `is_staff` to `True` in `create_superuser` method.

```
class CustomUserManager(...):
    # ...

    def create_superuser(...):
        # ...
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: It does not work. Returns me clashes with superclass.

Comment: @user2732966 Sorry about that. I didn't read your question carefully. I've updated the answer. See if it helps now.

Comment: Does not help yet. Same problem.